# How to move each box to the right, or to each first box does not move, but it remains the same

Tags: html, css

How to move each box to the right, or to each first box does not move, but it remains the same.
All red marked boxes to move to the right by 5 pixels, and each blue to remain in the same place.
So I wish that each box in the first row remains in place, without having to move to the right

https://s11.postimg.org/lyh9uaxwj/dsada.png

```css
#istaknuti_proizvodi_box_prikaza {
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 position: relative;
 background: #ccc;
 top:75.1px;
}
#istaknuti_proizvodi_prikaz {
 width:236px;
 height:250px;
 border:1px solid #000;
 position: relative;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 float:left;
 margin-top:2px;
}
#istaknuti_proizvodi_prikaz:nth-child(n+2){
 margin-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="istaknuti_proizvodi_box_prikaza">
<div id="istaknuti_proizvodi_prikaz"></div>
<div id="istaknuti_proizvodi_prikaz"></div>
<div id="istaknuti_proizvodi_prikaz"></div>
<div id="istaknuti_proizvodi_prikaz"></div>
<div id="istaknuti_proizvodi_prikaz"></div>
<div id="istaknuti_proizvodi_prikaz"></div>
<div id="istaknuti_proizvodi_prikaz"></div>
<div id="istaknuti_proizvodi_prikaz"></div>
<div id="istaknuti_proizvodi_prikaz"></div>
<div id="istaknuti_proizvodi_prikaz"></div>
<div id="istaknuti_proizvodi_prikaz"></div>
<div id="istaknuti_proizvodi_prikaz"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the code required to re-produce the issue in your question

Comment: Here I put code

Comment: Your question is still pretty unclear. What exactly is the issue, and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I wish that every box in the first row left to left, and every other box 5px move to the right, so this is what I want should look like this

https://s12.postimg.org/eh1egcpwt/ddddd.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not determine which one will come left. As by assuming 4 boxes fits your parent i have added the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3j8kckru/1/).

You can add `min-width` constrains to change it as the left most box changes. Likr `3n+1` for less width